# Is there a way I can mock _currencyRepository in this line of code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to do a unit test on a class using the MOQ framework. A public method in the class has a line like the below.

Looking at that line, I'm trying to mock the `_currencyRepository` but don't know how to. Considering it has a parameter like `p => new { p.Id, p.Code }`.

On analysing the code, it appears it is a way of outputting P - anonymous method I believe.

```
var currencies = await _currencyRepository.GetsAs(p => new { p.Id, p.Code }, p => p.Id == sellCurrencyId || p.Id == buyCurrencyId);
```

Hovering the mouse over var to get an idea of the type that get returns, the tootip shows `IEnumerable<'a> currencies. Anonymous types: 'a is new{Guid Id, string code}`.

..and GetAs definition is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TOutput>> GetsAs<TOutput>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TOutput>> projector,
                                               Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> spec = null,
                                               Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> preFilter = null,
                                               params Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>[] postFilters)
        {
            if (projector == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("projector");
            }

            return await FindCore(true, spec, preFilter, postFilters).Select(projector).ToListAsync();
        }
```

GetAs() is also a member/method in a Generic class `GenericRepository` - whose class definition is:

```
    public class GenericRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly TContext DbContext;
        public GenericRepository(TContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
        }

      //followed by method definitions including GetAs
}
```

The class above inherits from the generic interface `IGenericRepository<TEntity>`, which is defined as:

```
    public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
    {
        //list of methods including GetAs
         Task<IEnumerable<TOutput>> GetsAs<TOutput>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TOutput>> projector,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> spec = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> preFilter = null,
            params Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>[] postFilters);
```

...BaseEntity is just a class with properties:

```
    public class BaseEntity
    {
        public BaseEntity()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid? UpdateddBy { get; set; }

    }
```

I already have the list of currency that I'm trying to return, I'm just having errors with the parameters. Not sure what argument matchers to use (I'm aware argument matcher is NSubstitute talk. Not sure if it is called the same in Moq)

I tried a number of things. One of which is the below:

```
            var mockCurrencies3 = new[] { new { Id = buyCurrencyId, Code = "EUR" }, new { Id = sellCurrencyId, Code = "GBP" } };
            MockCurrencyRepository.Setup(x => x.GetsAs(
               It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Currency, (Guid, string)>>>(),
               It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Currency, bool>>>(),
               It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Currency>, IQueryable<Currency>>>()))
               .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockCurrencies3.AsEnumerable()));
```

Trying the above does not work as `mockCurrencies3` value is not getting returned in the production code. I don't get anything back.

Comment: Show the definition of the member you are trying to mock.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add that. I've just added the definition of GetAs(), which is an Async method.

Comment: Where does `TEntity` come from?

Comment: @Nkosi: So, GetAs is a member/method in the GenericRepository class which is generic and TEntity is one of the underlying type. This is the class declaration: ```    public class GenericRepository<TContext, TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
        where TContext : DbContext

Comment: That should be included in the question. If we are to be able to reproduce the issue we need to know the whole picture. Is this member part of a generic interface or just a generic class?

Comment: This member is part of the Generic interface `IGenericRepository<TEntity>` that the generic class `GenericRepository` inherits from.

Comment: Show the test that you have so far where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the provided information I was able to create a generic method to setup the desired behavior

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task  Should_Mock_Generic() {

        Guid buyCurrencyId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Guid sellCurrencyId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var mockCurrencies3 = new[] { new { Id = buyCurrencyId, Code = "EUR" }, new { Id = sellCurrencyId, Code = "GBP" } };

        var mock = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Currency>>();
        SetupGetAs(mock, mockCurrencies3);

        var _currencyRepository = mock.Object;

        var currencies = await _currencyRepository.GetsAs(p => new { p.Id, p.Code }, p => p.Id == sellCurrencyId || p.Id == buyCurrencyId);

        currencies.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty();
    }

    Mock<IGenericRepository<TEntity>> SetupGetAs<TEntity, TOutput>(Mock<IGenericRepository<TEntity>> mock, IEnumerable<TOutput> source)
        where TEntity : class {
        mock.Setup(x => x.GetsAs(
          It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, TOutput>>>(),
          It.IsAny<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>(),
          It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>>())
       )
       .ReturnsAsync(source);

        return mock;
    }

}
```

Comment: many thanks for this. I had to read up on a few things to use your solution.